# what is welding plate?

Tags: arduino-nano

I was looking at arduino nano boards [here](https://www.dhgate.com/product/new-5pcs-the-2014-version-arduino-nano-v3/388302235.html#s1-7-1b;searl%7C3376853976). Description says the arduino board is without welding plate. What does it mean for the user? If I buy this product will there be any issue? I understand that this board does not come with two headers soldered and I am OK with that.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a mistranslation of soldering. As far as I can tell, it just means that the headers are not soldered on.

(see https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Nano-V3-0-ATMEGA328P-improved-welding-plate-without-wiring-module-board/630494_32807228948.html for one with "welding plate")

Comment: Google [translates](https://translate.google.com/#auto/zh-TW/I%20soldered%20the%20wire%20to%20the%20circuit%20board.%20%0A%0AI%20welded%20the%20body%20to%20the%20chassis.%0A%0ASoldered.%0A%0AWelded.) both Soldered and Welded to 焊接 - I deduce that Chinese uses the same word for both - hence the mistranslation.